# 80's (?) sci-fi movie identification, cyborg, desert, isolation

Tags: story-identification, movie, cyborg

SPOILERS IN THE POST

I would like to identify a movie.

Probably it's been created in 80's (might be 70's or even early 90's).

What I can remember:

There's a group of people stuck in some facility (a factory? a ship?).
Water is scarce. I remember they were drinking from lavatory.
One of the guys turns out to be a cyborg, perhaps he's the evil one from the point it's discovered by others.
At the end some sort of gigantic robot or maybe a crane or some other device is started and perhaps it ultimately collapses on the cyborg.
Also it seems that there was a lot of sun, maybe they were on a desert or some similar desolate place (hence the lack of water).

Comment: Some of the plot points vaguely remind me of Aliens. See, for instance, [this page](http://reelclub.wordpress.com/2012/04/01/get-away-from-her-you-bitch-mother-vs-mother-in-aliens/). It would be strange that you wouldn't remember the aliens though.

Comment: This actually makes me think of Pitch Black. Not the 80's, but with a similar feel.

Comment: Sadly that's neither of the two movies.

Comment: What about Hardware? http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0099740

Comment: Some points of your description (mainly the infiltrated cyborg) remind me of [Screamers](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114367/).

Answer (score 6):

The movie you are talking about is [*Crash and Burn*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crash_and_Burn_%28film%29), released as *Robot Jox 2: Crash and Burn* in Europe.

[BadMovies.org plot summary](http://www.badmovies.org/movies/crashburn/)

> After watching numerous movies about the future I have decided it sucks, whether it be evil companies taking over, the development of killer robots, or an environment ruined by man's hubris. Unfortunately for the characters populating this movie, all three have happened; it has been a bad century.
>
> When the small group inhabiting a wasteland television station realizes one of their number might be a ruthless synthetic human, they do what every other group would do: rip off of John Carpenter's "The Thing." That is right, cut everyone's finger to see who bleeds oil, but it does not work since the robots are full of stage blood (oh, I mean red freon). Perhaps there was an easier way, like noticing that two characters never sweat even when everyone else is dripping wet! I noticed it, probably over half the audience noticed it, why did Tyson or Arren not notice it?
>
> Tyson does catch on to the fake people and soon a game of cat and mouse (if cats were made from steel and mice used shotguns) is played out through the station's dark corridors. None of it should surprise you, especially not one of the hookers deciding to take a shower and being killed. Only when things look hopeless does our heroine play her trump card, the DV-8.
>
> The video cover prominently displays the DV-8. It is an old mining or construction robot quietly rusting away in the local scrap heap. Arren has taken the time to fix it up and feels confident about piloting the thing. Despite a quick conversation in which we find out that it took "months" to learn the monster robot's controls, it does not look very difficult. If you want it to stand, then you type "stand." I am sure any other veteran Zork players out there would feel comfortable at the controls. In fact, screw throwing the rusty knife at the cyclops' eye, I want to type "punch cyclops in head" and be done with the annoying lout once and for all.
>
> You are going to spend the entire movie waiting for the DV-8 to do something cool, you are also going to be very disappointed. It walks about a hundred yards, lifts up a fallen girder, steps on Quinn - then falls to pieces. Obviously a GM product.

Answer (score 4):

Per @Kev's comment, I think it is [Hardware](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0099740/).

[image]

A great underrated movie, btw.

Comment: That was my initial thought too...

Comment: That movie comes up for more suggestions...

That said, the robot in Hardware is killed by being sprayed by a woman in a shower, which does not gibe with water shortage that would require people to drink from the toilet and it's not a crane.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the movie you seek might be this one:

I was looking for it too. :-)

Comment: Could you add some details to explain why it matches?

Answer (score 0):

I found this question while trying to find a movie I watched years ago. The one I was looking is *[Cyborg 3: The Recycler](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112765/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1)*. It has the same situation of taking place in the desert, with cyborgs having a free zone in a warehouse.

### Trailer

Comment: Unless you can provide details about how the movie is similar to the one in the question, this isn't very helpful. Can you please provide a description?

Comment: is the one you were looking for the same as the one being asked in the question?

Comment: I found this post by trying to find a movie I had watched, so yes the description s

Comment: The description reminded me of Cyborg 3. Takes place in the desert, where cyborgs had a free zone in this warehouse. The mainhttps://youtu.be/x0G9lWIlut4

Comment: https://g.co/kgs/MS0piH