# 90s or 80s Sci-Fi movie about a female cyborg / robot

Tags: story-identification, movie, cyborg

Please help identify an old movie I watched as a kid.

Plot (vaguely remembered): a group of people are trying to escape a facility (probably underground) and are pursued by a hard-to-kill / indestructible robot / cyborg. There are two main characters (male and female) who developed a romantic relationship.

They escape the facility in the end and find themselves in a desert. The female is a cyborg and is injured. She dies in the male's arms with a sort of a remote control with a cord out of her body. There is a teary goodbye and he shuts her down.

She might have given a birth or something.

I have recently watched and eliminated: Cyborg, Cyborg 2, Cyborg 3, Cyborg Cop 1, 2 and 3, Lunar Cop (quite close, but not it), Cyber Tracker 1 and 2

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You should check out the [suggestions for good story-id questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) to see if they help you remember any more details you can [edit] into your question.

Comment: You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Comment: I wonder if you are conflating a tv show episode and a movie -- the first part is a dead match for the Buck Rogers episode 'Unchained Women' -- mix that with part of the Cyborg movies and you might have what you are remembering.  Do you remember them being pursued by a nearly unstoppable android?  Of course, it's also possible the episode might have been inspired by the movie you are seeking (if you have the date off a bit; the episode was show in 1979), so YMMV :)

Answer (score 8):

I think you may be looking for *[Cyborg 2: Glass Shadow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdf49.jpg)*.

> In the year 2074 the PinWheel corporation creates an 'almost-human' cyborg Casella Reese, aka Cash, designed specifically to charm/seduce her way into a rival manufacturer's headquarters and then self-detonate. Things go awry, when she starts to have feelings for a human Colton Ricks, aka Colt 45, who works for PinWheel as a martial arts instructor. He falls for Cash as well, and with the help of Mercy, they escape. PinWheel Corp. sends Danny Bench, a 'Cyborg Tracker' after both Colt and Cash. Violence ensues.

It was following by a sequel, *[Cyborg 3: the Recycler](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112765/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1)*

> Prepare yourself for the all too deadly future. Cash, the heroine of Cyborg 2, is living safe in the free zone. But not for long. Biomechanical problems are taking down her systems and a visit to a doctor in Silica confirms her worst fears. She is more then a marvel of cyborg technology. She is the first of her kind to become a creator-she is pregnant.

What does not match, as you might guess from that she shows up in the sequel, is that Cash does not die after exiting the facility, although in *Cyborg 3*, the scene where Evans shows Cash is pregnant does have him holding what looks like a remote control, plugged into her.

[image: Evans diagnoses Cash's pregnancy using a device plugged into her abdomen]

### Trailer / "Best Parts"

Found by searching for `science fiction film facility escape desert cyborg`, which turned up [80's (?) sci-fi movie identification, cyborg, desert, isolation](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/55994/80s-sci-fi-movie-identification-cyborg-desert-isolation?rq=1), which has an answer referencing *Cyborg 3*, which led to me looking up what the prequel was.

Comment: Sounds dreadful. Add to basket.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answers. Unfortunately that's not it.
Forgot to mention what I have recently watched and eliminated:
Cyborg
Cyborg 2
Cyborg 3
Cyborg cop 1, 2 and 3
LunarCop (quite close, but not it)
Cyber tracker 1 and 2

Comment: I too am looking for a movie that sounds a lot like this, 
maybe the OP can confirm that the following
*also* appear in the movie he's looking for?:
The male hero goes by foot over land, being chased after by human-like robots.
He makes it to a small spaceship, but a robot prevents him
from esacping, damaging the ship or something
SPOILER BELOW
then, his girlfriend turns up, and she fights the robot.
The man manages to escape with his spaceship.

Comment: @mistige: I'd advise posting it as a new question, just in case it's something else entirely. You can always link this one in the question to indicate that you think it might be the same one.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like it could be [Nemesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nemesis_(1992_film))

In the movie, the main character Alex Raine is a cyborg former cop, in the first movie, his ex-lover, Jared is an android. With respect to her death, "It turns out that Jared was fatally wounded in her escape from LA, requiring her memory core to be salvaged from her body." I seem to remember lots of industrial settings and desert.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like [*Cherry 2000*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0092746/) (1987)... I vaguely remember this.

> In 2017, a successful businessman travels to the ends of the earth to find that the perfect woman is always under his nose. He hires a sexy renegade tracker to find an exact duplicate of his android wife.

Comment: I don't think this film matches the description given by OP

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this is [*Screamers*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114367/).

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to explain why you think this is answer.

Comment: You should explain specifically how this movie matches the details of the question, like the scene with a cord with a control coming out of the cyborg's body.

Answer (score -1):

[American Cyborg: Steel Warrior](http://American%20Cyborg:%20Steel%20Warrior)(1993)

> After World War III people are sterile and ruled by the artificial intelligences they created in this violent world. The only woman who was able to give life to a fetus has to take it through the dangerous city of Charleston, South Carolina to the port where a ship is on its way to Europe. She is followed by an android assassin through all the dangers, and only one man tries to help her survive and protect her from the killing machine.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Please [edit] your answer to describe the details of this movie that match the question.

Comment: It's not a bad partial match for details at that. Not certain about the plot reveal of her being a cyborg...