# Movie identification: female robot gives birth to baby

Tags: story-identification, movie

I watched a Sci-fi movie when I was young (around 1990-2000 I think?), I remember there was a robot rebellion fought against human, and what's important in the movie was a female robot giving birth to a baby.

The language was English, could be an American movie.

Can anybody give a hint?

EDIT: there was moral judge of whether to kill the female robot because she was able to give birth.

I think could recognise the back cover of the VCD if I see it. I'm surprised to see not many movies about this topic, thought it should be quite popular?

Comment: Anything else you can remember about this movie would be helpful in identifying it.  Theater, TV (what network or pay-TV service), streaming/YouTube?  Any specific technology other than the robots?  Remember any actors?

Comment: It was a Video CD, I'm not sure if it was robot or cyborg, I guess it was robot because in the movie there was moral judge whether to kill the robot because she gave birth to a child.

Comment: It sounds like the ending of RUR (Rossum's Universal Robots), the book that gave us the word "robot". There was a 1948 movie made of the book.

Comment: @NomadMaker no that's not it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to glob on a very similar title, *[Cyborg 3: the Recycler](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112765/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1)* has the eponymous cyborg (who is more robot than human), giving birth.

> Prepare yourself for the all too deadly future. Cash, the heroine of Cyborg 2, is living safe in the free zone. But not for long. Biomechanical problems are taking down her systems and a visit to a doctor in Silica confirms her worst fears. She is more then a marvel of cyborg technology. She is the first of her kind to become a creator-she is pregnant.

[image: Image of Cash in the process of giving birth]

### Trailer

I have not found a copy of the English box cover, but I think this is the one in Polish.

[image: Cyborg 3 box cover] (click for larger version)

This was my answer to [90s or 80s Sci-Fi movie about a female cyborg / robot](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/229359/90s-or-80s-sci-fi-movie-about-a-female-cyborg-robot/229360#229360), which is why it came to mind.

Comment: Wait, _that_ Malcolm McDowell?

Comment: Yup. Practically a cameo though.

Answer (score 5):

Could it be American Cyborg: Steel Warrior?
It is about Cyborgs and although the Woman who can give birth was human (well cyborg), she carries the fetus in a robotic looking jar thing.

> After the nuclear war people are sterile and ruled by the artifical
> intelligences they created in this violent world. The only woman who
> was able to give life to a child has to take the child through the
> dangerous city to the ship to save it. She is followed by an immortal
> killer robot through all the dangers, and only one guy tries to help
> her survive and protect her from the killing machine.

[image: pictures of cyborg heroine of the movie with her baby]

IMDB: https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0109098

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't seem to be it.